# How can I capture user input to pass parameter to HTTPS API call and return response to the user?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to pass user input from form to dynamically feed the API search, and then return the response to the user. User input is captured in the form, and I would like to pass it using form field ID. The code works on it's own in node, but I have to run it rather than it being triggered by the search button once the user inputs UPC

I was trying to use $.ajax call but with no luck; I am also having issues with HTTPS requirement not being recognized in the browser since it's a server side functionality

```
const https = require('https')
var opts = {
    hostname: 'api.upcitemdb.com',
    path: '/prod/trial/lookup',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",

    }
}
var req = https.request(opts, function (res) {
    console.log('statusCode: ', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers: ', res.headers);
    res.on('data', function (UPCoutput) {
        var UPCparsed = JSON.parse(UPCoutput);
        console.log('Product: ' + UPCparsed.items[0].title);
        console.log('UPC: ' + UPCparsed.items[0].upc);
        console.log('Image: ' + UPCparsed.items[0].images[0]);
        console.log('Price: ' + UPCparsed.items[0].offers[0].price);

    })
})
req.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

const userUPC = "604214384507"
const searchAPI = { upc: userUPC }

req.write(JSON.stringify(searchAPI))
req.end()
```

ideally I would pass a user input to the API call and return response to the user- not sure how to connect node to html.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce any issue with your code. In a browser (building your code with webpack) it runs fine and makes an HTTPS request. The only issue is that the fetch fails because it is a cross domain request and there is now CORS policy to allow it. If I run your code locally with Node it successfully issues a request over https and generates the expected output. You need to provide a minimal reproducible example of what is going wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Based on the documentation at https://www.upcitemdb.com/ I get the impression that it is not designed for cross domain access, which means you will need to create your own API (either on a subdomain of your website or with a CORS policy to allow requests from your website) that handles requests from your frontend and then makes a request to the UPC Item DB API.